# Java & NetBeans exercise, can't get it to work

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a beginner in coding and wanted to train, and so I started doing exercises that I find on the internet, I finished one and was unsatisfied because of how easy it was, and created myself a challenge.

The exercise was: you type in a variable and it tells you if it is above a certain number, in this case it's 50, but here's the thing, I didn't want to type it in, I want it to be randomly generated, but I can't find a way to solve the problem, it blocks at `nextInt`.

```
public class CheckPassFail { // saved as "CheckPassFail.java"
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      random r = new random ();
      int Low = 1;
      int High = 60;
      int mark = r.nextInt(High-Low)+ Low;
      System.out.println("The mark is " + mark);

      if (mark>50) {
         System.out.println("PASS");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Fail");
      }
   }
    private static class random {
        public random() {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it stops? Do you get an error message? Please post it.

Comment: Thankfully you have an inbuilt class to help. Use it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm

Comment: You don't need a custom class for that. Java already has a class called `Random`. Get rid of your `random` class and use Java's. Like this: `Random r = new Random();`. The rest of your code should work.

Comment: I can't see a `nextInt` method in `random` class. Is that a compilation error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Use Java's [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class instead of defining your own private static class.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CheckPassFail { // saved as "CheckPassFail.java"
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Random r = new Random ();
      int Low = 1;
      int High = 60;
      int mark = r.nextInt(High-Low)+ Low;
      System.out.println("The mark is " + mark);

      if (mark>50) {
         System.out.println("PASS");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Fail");
      }
   }
}
```